# Need Help about insert .asmx Service From Windows Phone

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, web-services, windows-phone-7, asmx

i cannot create code for inserting data from WinPhone to SQL Server via .asmx web service.

This is my .asmx's WebMethod code (it worked well from browser) :

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function insertRecord(ByVal sUserName As String, ByVal sPass As String, ByVal sEmail As String, ByVal sGender As String) As Integer

        sambung()  'open connection

        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into tblEmployee(UserName,Pass, Email, Gender) values('" & sUserName & "','" & sPass & "','" & sEmail & "','" & sGender & "')", koneksi)

        Dim row As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Return row
        putus()   'close connection
    End Function
```

And this is my WinPhone code :

```
    Protected Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim dbws As New Servis.insertRecordRequest
        Dim row As Integer = dbws.insertRecord(txtUserName.Text, txtPass.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtGender.Text)

            If row > 0 Then
                txtGender.Text = ""
                txtEmail.Text = txtGender.Text
                txtPass.Text = txtEmail.Text
                txtUserName.Text = txtPass.Text

            End If
    End Sub
```

Below is error code, i cannot find method ***insertrecord*** from .asmx (it just appear like "insertrecordRequest", "insertrecordresponse", etc). The error says it is unknown method. I already add service reference.

> Dim row As Integer = dbws.***insertRecord***(txtUserName.Text,
>   txtPass.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtGender.Text)

Any suggestion? Please help me, i will very happy if anybody answer my question. Thanks before. :)

*Note :
I've done add/update service reference. I just need code in WinPhone.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your Phone app is pointed to the correct Web Service.  Assuming you are building the web service too, make sure you "Update Service Reference" after you add new methods to the service.  The Phone app will not automatically regenerate the service reference, you have to manually do that when your service changes.

[Add/Update Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx)

Comment: Do you see any of your methods when you do this `dbws.`?

Comment: My method is "InsertRecord". But only appear InsertRecordRequest, InsertRecordResponse and such. It must shall appear "InsertRecord" but nothing.

Comment: No, i mean it must be "Dim dbws As New Servis.insertRecord" but just appear InsertRecordRequest and these foreign method. At dbws, it just appear like getdata, and unknown parameters.

Comment: What are you developing in: Winforms, WFP, Silverlight, Etc?

Comment: WinPhone, Winforms and asp.net.

Comment: C'mon, anybody can help me please. :(

Comment: Perhaps you are expecting the wrong thing. You should dimension a variable as the service and then from the service you should have have the methods you created.  `Dim dbws As New Servis.NameYouGaveServiceReference`   `dbws.InsertRecord(...)`